# How to write data received of API in MySQL without ignoring any data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rest

I'm creating a function in my controller where I send data to an API, I need to save the id from api of the product I sent, but that id is only supplied after insertion, so I create a query to get the last inserted product and insert in the mySQL table.

I select products you want to send.

```
$product = Product::where('erp_status', '=', 1)
          ->limit(10)
          ->offset($incrementer->cron_value)
          ->get();
```

I send the data to the API:

```
$r = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?access_token='.$token->erp_access_token, [
                  'json' => [
                      'title' => substr($prod->description->erp_name, 0, 60),
                      'category_id' => $cat2,
                      'price' => $prod->erp_price,
                      'currency_id' => 'BRL',
                      'available_quantity' => $prod->erp_quantity,
                      'buying_mode' => 'buy_it_now',
                      'listing_type_id' => 'gold_special',
                      'condition' => 'new',
                      'description' => utf8_encode($header),
                      'pictures' => [
                          ['source' => $prod->image->erp_image]
                      ]
                  ]
              ]);
```

I'll get the last one I sent:

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/239258430/items/search?status=active&access_token='.$token->erp_access_token.'&limit=1&order=stop_time_desc');
```

I put a `sleep (2);`

And save the result in 'erp_product_to_mlb' from my Database:

```
$a = $res->getBody();
$b = json_decode($a, true);
$mlb = new ProdMlb;
$mlb->erp_productid = $prod->erp_productid;
$mlb->erp_mlbid = $b['results'][0];
$mlb->save();
```

I run the code and works, but some records are being sent and are not being registered at the bank, can anyone tell me why? Importantly, it would be important that none be lost.

Comment: What do you get in `$r` from `$r = $client->request`?

Comment: I not get, I send to http://www.mercadolibre.com.ar/

Comment: When you POST the products to the api, will it return any response? Usually, the REST apis, return the data that is being posted along with the ids generated. If your api returns that response (which you can find from the variable `$r` above, then you dont need to make another GET call and can always be sure not to lose any data.

Comment: The mistake was this, it worked perfectly, thank you so much! @ayip